# Getting corresponding values in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset similar to this

```
Serial    A        B       
1         12               
1         31
1
1         12
1         31       203
1         10    
1         2
2         32       100     
2         32       242
2         3
3         2                
3         23       100     
3
3         23
```

I group the dataframe based on Serial and find the maximum value of each `A` column by `df['A_MAX'] = df.groupby('Serial')['A'].transform('max').values` and retain the first value by `df['A_MAX'] = df['A_MAX'].mask(df['Serial'].duplicated(), '')`

```
Serial    A        B       A_MAX    B_corresponding
1         12               31       203
1         31
1
1         12
1         31       203
1         10    
1         2
2         32       100     32       100
2         32       242
2         3
3         2                23       100
3         23       100     
3
3         23
```

Now for the `B_corresponding` column, I would like to get the corresponding `B` values of the `A_MAX`. I thought of locating the `A_MAX` values in `A` but there are similar max `A` values per group. Additional condition, for example in `Serial 2` I would also prefer to get the smallest `B` values between the `32`

Answer (score 2):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for maximal values per groups, then remove missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and get first rows by `Serial` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Create `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['A_MAX'] = df.groupby('Serial')['A'].transform('max')
df['A_MAX'] = df['A_MAX'].mask(df['Serial'].duplicated())

s = (df.sort_values(['Serial','A'], ascending=[True, False])
       .dropna(subset=['B'])
       .drop_duplicates('Serial')
       .set_index('Serial')['B'])
df['B_corresponding'] = df['Serial'].map(s).mask(df['Serial'].duplicated())
print (df)
    Serial     A      B  A_MAX  B_corresponding
0        1  12.0    NaN   31.0            203.0
1        1  31.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
2        1   NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN
3        1  12.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
4        1  31.0  203.0    NaN              NaN
5        1  10.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
6        1   2.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
7        2  32.0  100.0   32.0            100.0
8        2  32.0  242.0    NaN              NaN
9        2   3.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
10       3   2.0    NaN   23.0            100.0
11       3  23.0  100.0    NaN              NaN
12       3   NaN    NaN    NaN              NaN
13       3  23.0    NaN    NaN              NaN
```

Converting missing values to empty strings is possible, but get mixed values - numeric and strings, so next processing should be problematic:

```
df['A_MAX'] = df.groupby('Serial')['A'].transform('max')
df['A_MAX'] = df['A_MAX'].mask(df['Serial'].duplicated(), '')

s = (df.sort_values(['Serial','A'], ascending=[True, False])
       .dropna(subset=['B'])
       .drop_duplicates('Serial')
       .set_index('Serial')['B'])

df['B_corresponding'] = df['Serial'].map(s).mask(df['Serial'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
    Serial     A      B A_MAX B_corresponding
0        1  12.0    NaN    31             203
1        1  31.0    NaN                      
2        1   NaN    NaN                      
3        1  12.0    NaN                      
4        1  31.0  203.0                      
5        1  10.0    NaN                      
6        1   2.0    NaN                      
7        2  32.0  100.0    32             100
8        2  32.0  242.0                      
9        2   3.0    NaN                      
10       3   2.0    NaN    23             100
11       3  23.0  100.0                      
12       3   NaN    NaN                      
13       3  23.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dictionaries to achieve the same if you are not so inclined to only use pandas.

```
a_to_b_mapping = df.groupby('A')['B'].min().to_dict()
series_to_a_mapping = df.groupby('Series')['A'].max().to_dict()
agg_df = {}
for series, a in series_to_a_mapping.items():
    agg_df.append((series, a, a_to_b_mapping.get(a, None)))
  
agg_df = pd.DataFrame(agg_df, columns=['Series', 'A_max', 'B_corresponding'])
agg_df.head()
```

```
    Series  A_max   B_corresponding
0   1   31.0    203.0
1   2   32.0    100.0
2   3   23.0    100.0
```

If you want, you could join this to original dataframe and mask duplicates.

```
dft = df.join(final_df.set_index('Serial'), on='Serial', how='left')
dft['A_max'] = dft['A_max'].mask(dft['A_max'].duplicated(), '')
dft['B_corresponding'] = dft['B_corresponding'].mask(dft['B_corresponding'].duplicated(), '')
dft
```